# efibootmgr - Add FreeBSD to 3 Linux Installed Drive

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, efibootmgr

First of all, sorry for my English :)

I've read a lot of posts on internet but i cannot solve how to add an OS to UEFI boot list. I've recently installed FreeBSD 12 on my laptop.

Here is my laptop's state

- Lenovo T430 + UEFI + Secure Boot Off
- 3 Drive, GPT (1 SSD for Windows - 1 mSATA SSD for Linux - 1 HDD for Data)
- On mSATA = Ubuntu (main OS) + Kali + openSUSE (experimental OS) + FreeBSD

I normally press F12 (before first UEFI entry loads itself) to choose which OS i need to open, but after installing FreeBSD it didn't create its entry on UEFI by itself. As i searched, we can add OSes to UEFI Boot list by "efibootmgr".

My question is how can add FreeBSD to UEFI Boot List by efibootmgr ? I will be glad if someone can guide me.

Here is my lsblk and efibootmgr results. sdc7 is EFI partition of FreeBSD and sdc8 is / drive of it.

As you can see i have 2 EFI partition on same drive. FreeBSD created its own EFI drive and that's why i need to point this partition at command that i will wrote.

Will this command work ? Since i have 2 EFI partition on same drive, I use -p option instead of -d as everyone wrote on internet. I just don't want to corrupt UEFI with wrong command.

Do i need to run any more commands before run this command ?

```
sudo efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sdc -p 7 -l \\efi\\boot\\BOOTx64.efi -L freebsd
```

lsblk -f

```
sda                                                                   
├─sda1
│                                                                     
├─sda2
│    ntfs   Recovery
│                 2882D1D482D1A71A                                    
├─sda3
│    vfat         E0D3-5A76                              56,6M    41% /boot/efi
└─sda4
     ntfs   Windows
                  AEEEE327EEE2E715                                    
sdb                                                                   
├─sdb1
│                                                                     
├─sdb2
│    ntfs   Windows_Data
│                 46B8A33CB8A3297F                                    
├─sdb3
│    ntfs   Transfer_Data
│                 01D5962B6B1B0270                                    
└─sdb4
     ext4   Linux_Data
                  80f81b0e-99ce-416f-9599-03af50d533af    560G    27% /media/data
sdc                                                                   
├─sdc1
│                                                                     
├─sdc2
│    vfat         BEC4-D40C                                           
├─sdc3
│    ext4         7ba2f24a-caa6-49d2-99dc-8dd13277fc30   32,8G    41% /
├─sdc4
│    swap         4629bdd0-5bc9-4c3e-8bfb-c00ba5edad7a                [SWAP]
├─sdc5
│    ext4   KaliSystem
│                 b237a533-4cb1-452b-9e19-cb93e5312530                
├─sdc6
│    btrfs  openSUSESystem
│                 707b8c36-e278-4c58-ac65-e9ed9ae516f1                
├─sdc7
│    vfat   EFISYS
│                 BD41-11EE                                           
└─sdc8
     ufs          5e201901028bcd4a
```

efibootmgr

```
BootCurrent: 001A
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0001,0002,0003,0018,001A,0019,001B,0007,0008,0009,000A,000B,000C,000D,000E,000F,0011,0010,0012
Boot0000  Setup
Boot0001  Boot Menu
Boot0002  Diagnostic Splash Screen
Boot0003  Lenovo Diagnostics
Boot0004  Startup Interrupt Menu
Boot0005  ME Configuration Menu
Boot0006  Rescue and Recovery
Boot0007* USB CD
Boot0008* USB FDD
Boot0009* ATAPI CD0
Boot000A* ATA HDD0
Boot000B* ATA HDD1
Boot000C* ATA HDD2
Boot000D* USB HDD
Boot000E* PCI LAN
Boot000F* ATAPI CD1
Boot0010  Other CD
Boot0011* ATA HDD3
Boot0012  Other HDD
Boot0013* IDER BOOT CDROM
Boot0014* IDER BOOT Floppy
Boot0015* ATA HDD
Boot0016* ATAPI CD:
Boot0017* PCI LAN
Boot0018* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0019* opensuse-secureboot
Boot001A* ubuntu
Boot001B* kali
```

Answer (score -1):

I used the command that i told but i had nonvolatile memory full error.

To solve issue,
I've removed the entry at UEFI that i've recently created
Deleted dump files on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
Run the efibootmgr command again

Hope this can be helpful who will face same issue